# Tag Privacy on Shared Files

Tags: data-transfer, privacy, finder-tag

Are tags on uploaded files able to be seen by the recipient once they open and save the file to their own system (Apple or Microsoft)?

If so, is there a way to prevent that?

(Besides the obvious, "don't tag it with something you don't want others to see" - it's a divorce case and some of the necessary tags on some shared files would create additional and unnecessary paranoia in the other party)

Comment: To be on the safe side it might help to create copies without any tags and share those.

Comment: What file types are you talking about, specifically?

Comment: Pages, png or pdf files for discovery.  Receiving lawyer won't look, but receiving client client (Former Intel Officer, paranoia, unpredictable and unstable behavior) will.  Spouse has information with multiple tags for for incidents relating to mental/emotional/financial abuse on documents.  The documents themselves won't necessarily raise red flags because they are copies of initiated interactions, emails, snapshots of bank accounts which were asked for.  It would unnecessarily put the other person in an oppositional state earlier than would be safe.

Comment: NoHillside_ Thought about that, but the volume of files is prohibitive to do this quickly and efficiently. Would do for last resort, but was hoping to hear that personal tags do not transfer.  

Although you did give me an idea, don't know why this didn't occur earlier - an entire set of tags can be renamed.   https://osxdaily.com/2019/09/09/how-rename-tags-mac/

However, still curious if tags can be seen.